# Generic Classes and Subtyping

Tags: java, generics, subtyping

Studying Generic types.... This is an example from Oracle:

```
interface PayloadList<E,P> extends List<E> {
  void setPayload(int index, P val);
}
```

The following parameterizations of PayloadList are subtypes of List:

```
PayloadList<String,String>
PayloadList<String,Integer>
PayloadList<String,Exception>
```

Can someone help with an live example of PayloadList interface implementation?

Comment: What is `setPayload` for? _Extending_ `List` is generally not  that useful: composition tends to be a better idea than inheritance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: This is an example from Oracle see the link. This is the reason I am asking))) not clear whats for and how...

Answer (score 1):

Despite this being in an Oracle tutorial, I think this is a poor example.

[The page you link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) says:

> Now imagine we want to define our own list interface, PayloadList, that associates an optional value of generic type P with each element

Well, that's not really a `List` any more.

I doubt that anybody has ever actually (seriously) implemented this interface.

If you wanted to implement it, just implement all of the required methods. It would probably be easiest to implement most of the methods by delegating to an existing implementation of `List`, which strongly points to the fact that *composition*, rather than *inheritance*, was the correct way to model the class adding this "payload" functionality.

That is, the "list with associated payloads" class isn't considered to be a "list" any more: it's a thing which holds a list, and payloads.

Comment: Yes, agree with you. Just was scratching my head trying to understand this "imagine". Tried to make an example and that as you are saying requires implementation of methods declared in List